# How to configure Node for Android/ iOS devices for Selenium Grid testing?

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I'm learning Selenium Grid from scratch.I'm able to run scripts from my hub to my node systems. But when it comes to using android and ios devices as nodes, I've this confusion.

1. I do not understand if Android/ios device as a node should be configured in the same system where Hub is running?
   (I was going through a tutorial, with this setup, so I wanted to clarify this point).
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49d25lj59s&list=PLUeDIlio4THHz9tkkg3uLUYpfxE4SoUfY&index=1
2. If my target node(ex:- System B) has an android device running on it, can grid run scripts on that device from Hub(ex:- System A)?
   If yes, then will the appium should be running in System-A(hub) or System-B(Node)?